# Books on Dielectric mirrors

Tags: optics, resource-recommendations, reflection, dielectric

I'm looking for books that can introduce me to dielectric mirrors, as one of my professors wants me to join them on a project on the subject. Any recommendation is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, dielectric mirrors are just a bunch of dielectric slabs in contact, where the refractive indices, thicknesses and number of slabs are chosen such that the total (this is a interference type of total not just simple addition) reflected wave is maximized and transmitted wave is minimized. As such, dielectric mirror designs are highly wavelength and polarization dependent. I think it would benefit the OP to learn about some dielectric electromagnetics. There may be books specific to dielectric mirrors but I am unable to provide such specific sources currently, and I do think the OP can find the needed information in the below electromagnetics book below:

- **[Electromagnetic Waves and Antennas](http://eceweb1.rutgers.edu/%7Eorfanidi/ewa/)** by Sophocles J. Orfanidis is a comprehensive book, which I found easy to follow and has a lot of examples to show different situations. The link contains the book chapters and some supplementary stuff, free of charge from the author himself. The MATLAB exercises are very helpful and the same webpage also contains the link for the MATLAB toolbox the author readily provides.

Another thing that is somewhat fast and useful would be to simply go to a vendor's website and try to read and understand what's written there. I find Thorlabs information blips (for example on the page where they are showing their dielectric mirrors) to be a source of practical and general information, although scientifically incomplete. So, this would be a place to just check out mostly for fun, which would show the OP the wavelength dependence and polarization dependence visually and instantly. (I am not sure about the ethical implications of posting a vendor link as a resource link, so I opted not to do that. A simple Google search with the vendor name and "dielectric mirror" would reveal the page to which I am referring. Please let me know if this is in any way problematic.)

I hope this helps. Best of luck to the OP.